# Как отформатировать числа через Regexp?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Есть строка вида

> 123.0,234,5677,"34,56",34.56,67.89

То есть все нормальные числа имеют разделитель точку и между собой разделены запятыми, однако некоторые имеют разделитель запятую а для разделения помещены в кавычки, внутри возможен и пробел как разделитель порядка ("1 000,00").

Как мне написать Regexp который все неправильные цифры заменит на правильные, то есть на цифру с разделителем точкой?

Comment: Это четкая закономерность, что если разделитель дробной и целой части запятая, то число в кавычках?  
Или возможна ситуация, что внутри кавычек разделитель точка? `"12.34"`

Comment: Думаю что невозможна, на данный момент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
str.replaceAll.(" ", "").replaceAll("\"(-?\\d+)(?:,(\\d*))?\"", "$1.$2")
```

Ограничения:
Не учитывается возможность чисел в которых целая часть равна нулю вида `",123"`

Answer (score 0):

JS, переписать на Java не должно составить труда)

```
in_re = /(?=(?:(?:"[^"]+){2})*)"(\d*)[,.]*(\d*)?"/gm;
out_re = '$1.$2\0';
in_str = '123.0,234,5677,"34,56",34.56,67.89,123.0,234,5677,"34,56",34.56,67.89';
out_str = in_str.replace(in_re, out_re);
```

Либо так

```
in_re = /(?:"(\d*)[,.]?(\d*)"|(\d*)\.?(\d*))(,|$)/gm;
out_re = '$1$3.$2$40$5';
in_str = '123.0,234,5677,"34,56",34.56,67.89,123.0,234,5677,"34,56",34.56,67.89';
out_str = in_str.replace(in_re, out_re);
```

Comment: А как же пробелы в качестве разделителя порядков?

Comment: Для пробелов следует воспользоваться вашим кодом))

    str.replaceAll.(" ", "")